# why login page in asp.net mvc loads very slow?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

this is my controller

```js
 #region Authentication
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
        {
            // Lets first check if the Model is valid or not
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                

                    bool userValid = itreedb.Users.Any(user => user.UserName == username && user.Password == password && user.Approved == true);

                    // User found in the database
                    if (userValid)
                    {
                        //
                        // Save un and pw into cookies
                        HttpCookie auth = new HttpCookie("auth", Request.Form["username"] + "|" + Request.Form["password"]);
                        auth.Expires.AddDays(30);
                        Response.Cookies.Add(auth);

                        // Redirect the user to the index page
                        return Json(new { IsValidLogin = true });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                    }
                
            }
            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View();
        }
```

When I try to insert my admin informations it takes more than 5 minutes to be authentified .The others pages reload normally. What can I do?

`

Comment: Did you try any profilers to see where it is taking time ? Glimpse ? MiniProfiler ?

Comment: I use breakpoints to locate the blocking and it  seems stopping in `  if (ModelState.IsValid)`